# Finding function with a certain given gradient

Tags: determinant, vector-analysis, transformation, substitution

###### Question:

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be convex and open with compact closure, $\varphi\in W^{1,p}(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$ for $2<p<\infty$ and $\Phi:\Omega\to\Omega$ a diffeomorphism. Can I find a function $\psi\in W^{1,p}(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$
\nabla \psi(y) = \nabla\varphi(\Phi(y)) \cdot |\det D\Phi(y)|
$$

holds?

IISC the naive choice $\psi(y) = \varphi(\Phi(y))$ does not do the trick (the chain rule gives $D\Phi$ rather than $|\det D\Phi|$).

---

###### Background:

I have some function $q\in L^{p'}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^d)$ satisfying
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla \varphi \cdot q = - \int_\Omega \varphi\mu \quad \forall \varphi\in W^{1,p}(\Omega,\mathbb{R})
$$

for some scalar valued $\mu$ satisfying $\int_\Omega \mu = 0$
and I'd like this to also hold true for $q\circ\Phi^{-1}$. So the determinant comes from the transformation formula.

Actually, for now I only consider the case $\Omega=B_r(0)$ and $\Phi(y) = \eta(|y|) y$ where $\eta:[0,r] \to [0,r]$ is a diffeomorphism, but if it works out, I'd like to extend the result to more general sets and transformations.

Comment: In your background is $\varphi$ supposed to be a real valued function or a vector valued function? If it is vector valued, then $\nabla \varphi$ is a matrix and $\nabla \varphi\cdot q$ is a vector, but $c$ is supposed to be a real number. In your original question i would have expected $\Omega$ to be open, with compact closure. Otherwise it would be tricky to define a derivate.

Comment: The constant $c$ has to be 0 (test with $\varphi=0$ for instance). It seems to me like you're trying to preserve something like $\text{div}( q)=\text{constant}$ under a change of variables for $q$; I don't think that's feasible without some assumptions on the map $\Phi$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! you're both right and I edited the question accordingly. @Jose27 what kind of assumptions do you have in mind?

Comment: Ok, so the thing you're trying to preserve is the solution to the PDE:$$\begin{cases}\text{div}(q) =\mu & \text{ in } \Omega\\ q\cdot \nu = 0 & \text{ on } \partial\Omega,\end{cases}$$ where $\nu$ denotes the exterior unit normal. Are you allowed to alter $\mu$ (depending on $\Phi$ of course)? If so, it would make sense I think, at least with the special choice of $\Phi$ that you mention at the end since those in principle will preserve the boundary condition. I doubt this can be done, even in the case of a ball, for a general $\Phi$.

Comment: Yes, I can alter $\mu$. More precisely, the support of $\mu$ is only a subset of $B_{r_0}=K\subset\Omega$ and $\Phi$ is the identity on $K$. $\Phi$ is basically supposed to "shrink" $\Omega\setminus K$ to some $B_R(0)\setminus K$ ($r_0<R<r$). Sorry for not including all the info in the question right away - finding a good trade off between asking a somewhat short question and providing enough context is not always easy (at least for me) …